# SQL error when installing Joomla add-on

Tags: joomla, mysql

I am trying to install the add-on for Joomla, but I get the following error message:

`` Cannot execute CREATE TABLE `civicrm_extension` ( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Local Extension ID', `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL, `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fully qualified extension name', `name` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Short name', `label` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Short, printable name', `file` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Primary PHP file', `schema_version` varchar(63) COMMENT 'Revision code of the database schema; the format is module-defined', `is_active` tinyint DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Is this extension active?', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE INDEX `UI_extension_full_name`(full_name), INDEX `UI_extension_name`(name) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes ``

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM

You will need the following MySQL server configuration:

```
innodb_large_prefix=true 
innodb_file_format=barracuda 
innodb_file_per_table=true
```

add above configuration in your [my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758) file.

See [mysql requirement](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-configuration) for CiviCRM